# why the result is not expected?

Tags: c, loops

I have some code as following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static counter = 0;
static flag = 0;

int main()
{
    int number = 3;
    int i = 0;
    for(i; i< number; i++)
    {
        if(counter >= number)
        {
            counter = 0;
            flag = 1;
        }
        counter ++;

        printf("   counter = %u\n", counter);
        printf("   flag = %u\n", flag);

    }



    return 0;
}
```

everytime when the counter reach 3, the flag should be 1, but why when counter reach 3, the flag is still 0?

Comment: because `i` never reaches `3` as per the code. Try `i <= number`

Comment: if I only want to loop 3 times, loop reaches third times, set flag to 1?

Comment: Then you can put `counter++` just next to `for`. I mean before the `if`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You loop runs only 3 times. In the last iteration, during the `if` test, value of `counter` is 2 and value of `number` is 3. And the if test fails. Now counter is incremented to 3 which is what is printed.

Answer (score 2):

you do not reach `if`-section

when i = 3 you have counter = 2 and pass out from cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Because code inside `if` is never executed as the condtion in the for fails when `i` becomes 3.

Answer (score 1):

you increase `counter` after your conditional, so if u determine `counter >= number` it will be 2 at max.

Comment: try `counter++` at the line before `if(counter >= number)`

Answer (score 0):

Because the code below is never reached and program came out of loop

```
if(counter >= number)
        {
            counter = 0;
            flag = 1;
        }
```

so `counter=3` and `flag` will remain `0`

If you want to set it to `0` when it comes out of loop then just do

`counter++` above the `if` statement and delete the other `counter++`(which is below the if)